# grails render collection as single json object

Tags: json, grails

For example I have next Domain class

```
User{
   String name
}
```

Also I have 2 objects of this class

```
new User(name: "John").save()
new User(name: "Alex").save()
```

How should look "list" action in UserController to represent User.list() in JSON format like this

```
{1: "John", 2: "Alex"}
```

Let me be more precise. I want something like this:

```
UserController{
   def list = {
    render(contentType: "text/json") {
        User.list().each {user->
            user.id = user.name
        }
    }
}
```

But sadly this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find solution with JSONBuilder API. Because of that I made my solution with help of org.codehaus.jackson.

```
response.setContentType("text/json")
JsonGenerator g = jsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(response.getOutputStream())
g.writeStartObject()
for (user in users) {
    g.writeStringField(user.id.toString(), user.name)
}
g.writeEndObject()
g.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the array structure,

```
def list = {
    render(contentType: "text/json") {
        results = array {
            User.list().each {user->
                result "${user.id}" : "${user.name}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your idea but it produces [{"1":"John"},{"2":"Alex"}] instead of {"1":"John", "2":"Alex"}.

Comment: yes its an array of one. that's the best i could do :). you can try using JsonBuilder directly

Comment: For GRAILS3 seems not to work anymore array; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When I want to encode something as JSON in grails, I put everything in maps:

```
render ['1':john.name, '2':alex.name] as JSON
```

Comment: This is answering my question, but IMO this is bad soultion. You creating extra map instead of using converter API.

Comment: It's not ideal but it's working. And there is some advantage. I was not fond of converting to JSON in the controller. In production code, I returns a map from the controller and I use a Filter in order to apply some generics operations while encoding as JSON (optional pretty print, jsonp wrapping...).

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @aldrin answer, a correction is needed for GRAILS3 json rendering because `array` directive is no more working (and is more correct 'application' instead of 'text'), so the solution must be

```
def list = {
def ulist = User.list()
render(contentType: "application/json") {
    results(ulist) { user ->
                 userid  user.id
                 username  user.name
    }
}
}
```